# Making an image the head of a card | Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a card which looks like this

[image]

I'm wondering if it would be possible to change the gray head part to be the picture that's inside of it right now.

My HTML code

```html
<div class="card-set">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <img src="../../img/boxA.jpeg" style="width: 300px;">
      </div>
      <div class="card-body"></div>
      <div class="card-footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
      <img src="../../img/boxB.jpeg" style="width: 300px; height: 70px;">
      </div>
      <div class="card-body"></div>
      <div class="card-footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header"></div>
      <div class="card-body"></div>
      <div class="card-footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header"></div>
      <div class="card-body"></div>
      <div class="card-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re asking if the image can fill the full size of the card-header, yes, if you set the padding to 0, hide the overflow (the overflow is so the image corners follow the header border-radius), and set the image to 100% width.

```
<div class="card-set">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header overflow-hidden p-0">
        <img class="w-100" src="boxA.jpg" >
      </div>
      <div class="card-body"></div>
      <div class="card-footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <img src="boxB.jpg" >
      </div>
      <div class="card-body"></div>
      <div class="card-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don’t have any rows or columns in your sample, so the width will expand to fill the available space (and the image will adjust accordingly).